# How I predict how some formula will behave with integers?

Tags: algorithm, integer

I am making some software that need to work with integers.
Also I need to apply some formula to those integers, repeatedly over time (example, do x/=z several times in a row for a indefinite amount).

All tools, algorithms and formulas I could think or find, or don't work with integers at all, or work as approximations at best.

For example the x/=z several times in a row for example, you can theoretically calculate what x will be in the 10th time by doing x = x/(z^10), but that will be wrong if the result is fractional, you can use floor(x/(z^10)), but the result will STILL be wrong.

Plotting software that I found also don't have integers at all, or has "floor()/ceil()" functions support, at best, and still the result would fall in the problem of the previous paragraph.

So how I do it?

Comment: How are you computing x/z^10? In what circumstance does what you do produce what unexpected result?

Comment: what do you mean by "predict"? it looks like you want to calculate the exact value.

Comment: also, what kind of formulas are we talking about? without restrictions, I fear we are back to the halting problem...

Comment: relatively simple formulas can produce fractal-like behaviour. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: I mean predict, because when I am designing games (although this particular project is for financial industry, not games) I tend to use plotting tools, spreadsheets or some other tools to design the formulas I will use (for example: if I am making an RPG, I might use a plotting tool to figure what formula would result in players killing a monster of their own level on average in 3 turns...)

Comment: So? Just iteratively calculate the result. If you're designing a formula, performance is surely not a concern.

Comment: The problem is not performance, it is that I like to tweak values and formulas until I see something I like, since I am using mostly compiled languages, just the compile time for each attempt can be absurdly annoying, I would like predict my program behaviour before compiling and running it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you going for the iteration of x/=z:

[image]
(that should have ended in "all three terms are 0 with regard to integer division")

Now if x or z are negative, you can try and see whether this still holds; I did not invest the time to make the necessary case distinctions, but they should be fairly analogous.

---

As Karoly Horvath mentions in a comment, without a clear specification of the kinds of functions for which you would like to find a shortcut to replace iterative evaluation, helping you out won't be possible since there are uncountably many functions over the integers, and the same approach won't work for all of them.